# Outcomes of the Greek Life for a graduate student

Tags: graduate-school, academic-life

A graduate student's main task would be the concentration on the research and scientific stuffs for stepping on the path of progression, as well as possible.

Social programs within the university would be effective in cultural view point, but could distract the student's concentration and waste his/her time. One might assert that a typical social program would be such useful (in perspective of the personal and social denouements) that the risk of the imbalance within the time sharing between expecting research and extracurricular activities could be neglected.

***Greek Life*** is just among both the most intriguing social programs and most time-consuming ones.

What kind of outcomes could be conceived for a graduate student, who takes part in ***Greek Life***, actively?

Comment: Are graduate students even eligible to join most fraternities / sororities?  I had the impression that they were generally restricted to undergraduates.

Comment: When you say Greek life, do you mean fraternities/sororities and the like? It's my impression that most frats are undergrad only, at least in the US.

Comment: Most of the social Greek letter organizations at U.S. campuses that I've seen don't include graduate students.  Whether this is by design or by outcome I'm not sure, though I would think it's a combo of the two.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Greek Life has been defined for graduate students in some US universities. Please find `Naraht` thread here:http://www.greekchat.com/gcforums/showthread.php?t=133906

Comment: If it's true that Greek Life is an option for grad students, then this question is surely useful (and shouldn't be downvoted). I get the distinct impression that people are downvoting this because they think the idea of joining a frat as a grad student is absurd...(maybe it is...)

Comment: @APrioriRainbows There is also the problem that the OP assumes that we know what "greek life" is. I as an European academic honestly have no idea. Question that I don't even understand equals downvote until fixed.

Comment: @xLeitix I see your point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To restate what everyone is saying in an answer:
this usually isn't an option for graduate students.

To say a bit more...
Your time in graduate school should be career focused. There will be plenty of departmental activities that will provide an outlet for socialization (and dare I say drinking). If joining a frat/sorority is even possible, it's a bad idea.
You should be making connections with your academic peers and professors--not other university students generally.

Comment: It clears the situation...

Comment: I think it's good to make some social connections outside your department. I joined my university's outdoors club and karate club and really enjoyed my experience, including meeting a range of students. But I agree that joining a fraternity or sorority would be a bad idea (if it were possible).

Comment: @Anonymous Yes. I didn't mean that you avoid all non-departmental social activities. But in terms of how Greek life relates directly to your success in graduate school? It doesn't. Just as joining the outdoors club doesn't relate directly to a graduate program. But it's a nice social opportunity that you can take advantage of through your university.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, I don't know of any graduate student Fraternities (I attend FSU). However, as a grad student your experience has some similarities of a frat, at least in my experience. You are in classes with the same (or many of the same) people every day. Our business school has many gatherings and social events for the entire business school as well as within each specific department. I am now in the PhD program and there is a PhD student association that also has many gatherings. The people you go through these types of degrees become your brothers, as you both struggle to overcome the same obstacles. So it's similar to a fraternity, but instead of "obstacles" meaning sliding down a slip and slide with another drunk guy into a human pyramid of cheerleaders, you are trying to pass a quantitatively intense test with another person seeking a professional career. Yea, they're basically one in the same ;)